# How to uninstall Ruby on Rails plugin with migrations easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a Rails application with numbered migrations 001_..., 002_..., etc.

I have several plugins A,B,C with their own migrations 001_.., 002_... etc.
How to remove the particular plugin B and clean the schema (making B plugin migrations *down*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they were migrated in order A B C then migrate back to A state remove Plugin B and Plugin B's migration then migrate to current

should do the trick

Comment: Any tips on exact steps to do? Thanks.

Comment: lets say you have migrations 001 002 003 for plugins A B C respectively and you want to remove plugin A

rake db:migrate:down VERSION=001
go into vender/plugins and delete plugin A directory

that should do it